# ipa file too big when made with fastlane

Tags: ios, swift, ipa, fastlane

I am having this lane:

```
platform :ios do
  desc "Sends build to the App Store"
  lane :release do

   increment_build_number
   build_app(
               clean: true,
               export_method: 'app-store',
               scheme: "fastlane-integration-ios"
   )

   verify_build(
       bundle_identifier: "xxx.com.fastlane-integration"
   )

   #sync_code_signing(type: "appstore")  # see code signing guide for more information

   capture_screenshots(
    scheme: "fastlane-integration-ios-ui-tests",
    configuration: "Release",
    sdk: "iphonesimulator",
    stop_after_first_error: true
   )


   upload_to_app_store(
    submit_for_review: true,
    force: true,
    automatic_release: false,
    skip_metadata: false,
    skip_screenshots: false,
    run_precheck_before_submit: true,
    overwrite_screenshots: true
   )
   #slack(message: "Successfully uploaded a new App Store build")
  end
end
```

and the .ipa file end up 1.45 GB big. Why is this happening? My application is test application and has only two screens and no images.

Comment: Can you open the .ipa and see what's taking all that space?

Comment: I can’t I deleted it :) Now it works fine. I am not sure what made it that big.